# static standards: Non-Static method Date utility

Tags: php, mysql

Strict Standards: Non-static method DateUtility::subtractDaysFromDate() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/zumpu/public_html/cats/cats-0.8.0/modules/activity/ActivityUI.php on line 449

Strict Standards: Non-static method DateUtility::addDaysToDate() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/zumpu/public_html/cats/cats-0.8.0/lib/DateUtility.php on line 285

```
public function subtractDaysFromDate($startDate, $daysToSubtract)
    {
        return self::addDaysToDate($startDate, ($daysToSubtract * -1)); //285 line
    }
```

> // first error code line 449

```
private function makeQuickLinkURL($dayOfWeek)
    {
        /* PHP's date('w') uses 0-6 to represent weekdays, but the CATS weekday
         * constants use 1-7.
         */
        $dayOfWeek--;

        $currentDate = time();
        $daysDifference = date('w', $currentDate) - $dayOfWeek;

        $linkDate = DateUtility::subtractDaysFromDate($currentDate, $daysDifference);//**line 449**

        switch ($daysDifference)
        {
            case -1:
                $dayString = '<span style="display: inline;">Tomorrow</span>';
                break;

            case 0:
                $dayString = '<span style="color: #ff6600; display: inline;">Today</span>';
                break;

            case 1:
                $dayString = '<span style="display: inline;">Yesterday</span>';
                break;

            default:
                $dayString = date('l', $linkDate);
                break;
        }

        $month = date('n', $linkDate);
        $day   = date('j', $linkDate);
        $year  = date('Y', $linkDate);
```

Help me with this error

Comment: The warning is pretty obvious: `addDaysToDate()` is not defined as a static method, but you're trying to call it as though it is, so either make it static, or call it using `$this->addDaysToDate()` instead of `self::addDaysToDate()`

Comment: thank you for your reply but still i didnt fix my problem, now i am having a fatal error

Comment: If you're getting a fatal error now, what do the logs show? And you also need to change `subtractDaysFromDate()` to a static method, or call it as an instance method

Answer (score 0):

You have more than one issue here:

In your instance method `subtractDaysFromDate()` you call `addDaysToDate()` statically, which is also instance method. Then you need to call it with `$this->`. But it will produce fatal error for one simple reason:

`$this` refers to the current instance, but you have none:

`$linkDate = DateUtility::subtractDaysFromDate($currentDate, $daysDifference);`

Because `subtractDaysFromDate()` is called statically, you have no instance.

You should either decide if these methods are static and add the keyword `static` on both of them, or call them via instance of the class.

In this case `DateUtility` class needs to be instantiated.

```
$dateUtility = new DateUtility();
$linkDate = $dateUtility->subtractDaysFromDate($currentDate, $daysDifference);
```

then

```
public function subtractDaysFromDate($startDate, $daysToSubtract)
    {
        return $this->addDaysToDate($startDate, ($daysToSubtract * -1)); //285 line
    }
```